# Как прервать работу потока(остановить поток)

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я делал програму на Java с использованием нескольких потоков, и столкнулся с проблеммой: я не знаю как прервать работу потока. Я пытался это сделать с помощью метода stop() но потоку как-будто просто пофигу(хотя я проверял в отдельном файле и там он сработал), и метод interrupt() тоже не работает, не знаю почему. Короче подскажите способ, желательно попроще, как прервать работу потока.

Comment: Приведите ваш код, который у вас не работает, чтобы было о чём вообще разговаривать. Добавьте его прямо в вопрос - вы можете его редактировать и улучшать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри метода run() потока можно проверять в цикле значение isInterupted:

```
public void run() {
    int i=0;
    while(!isInterrupted()){
        System.out.println(i++);
        try {
            sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

и вызывать из основного потока метод interupt(), когда нужно прервать поток.

Comment: спасибо, но я уже сам нашел в чём была проблемма, теперь всё работает